# Explaining odd behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript

I saw this on twitter and I couldn't explain it either. Defining a `onload` function in the following two manner works:

## 1) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rq9k/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            onload = function(){
                alert('this works');
            };
        </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>​
```

## 2) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rq9k/1/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                alert('this works');
            };
        </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>​
```

But when defined like the following, it doesn't work even though it is assigned to `window.onload`

## 3) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rq9k/2/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function onload(){
                alert('this doesnt work');
            };
            alert(window.onload); // this shows the definition of above function
        </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>​
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Your question really intrigued me, and I'm doing some research. I'm not sure it's because of hoisting as dystroy said. It might be related to the way browsers deal with event handlers, but I'm also not sure of that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first two examples assign a function to the `window.onload` property (`window.` is implicit in the first example). The `onload` property actually belongs to the *prototype* of `window` (conveniently called `Window`).

The third variant declares a new *local* function with the same name, and that function shadows the property from the prototype. This means, when you ask for `window.onload`, the engine finds the local version first, and gives up looking up the prototype chain. So `alert(window.onload);` does alert your function source. However, for the event handler to work, it would have to be assigned to the prototype object's `onload` property.

However, there is something odd going on: when you try to assign to a property that's inherited from the `prototype`, it shouldn't work, and an "own" property should be created on the object, shadowing the one from the prototype (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ssBt9/). But `window` behaves differently (http://jsfiddle.net/asHP7/), and the behavior may even vary depending on the browser.

Comment: What does shadow mean, is it a technical term? I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't execute when it still can be referenced from `window.onload`. Can you add more explanation?

Comment: May as well add that functions declared in the global scope become properties of the window object, but it still shadows the original window's `onload` property. http://jsfiddle.net/Ad7JG/1/

Comment: Turns out my answer was **sort of** correct. But I had to ask a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809917/are-directly-assigned-event-handlers-actual-object-properties) to realize that.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. In both first cases, you're also directly assigning the property of window, not on its prototype.

Comment: @dystroy I'm still researching this issue, but apparently `window.onload = function(){}` and `onload=` *do* assign to a property of the prototype, instead of creating an own property that shadows the one from the prototype. Host objects can behave differently sometimes, and `window` is behaving differently in this case. This is a possible explanation: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-windowproxy-object

Comment: I think my answer is right but it's possible the confirmation could only be given using the sources of a browser *and* a js engine. If you know somebody from Chrome's team or Mozilla, don't hesitate to send them the link ;)

Comment: @dystroy I wish I did, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: I hesitate to submit it on [/r/javascript](http://reddit/r/javascript). Sometimes there are insightful people but often there are just pretentious ones simply telling RTFM as soon as they don't understand. And I'm not sure it's worthy of [HN](http://news.ycombinator.com/).

Comment: @dystroy Don't worry. I'll try to discuss it in the SO chat later. Tried yesterday but nobody cared. BTW, here is what makes me believe `Window.prototype` is actually being changed: http://jsfiddle.net/asHP7/ (versus http://jsfiddle.net/ssBt9/, as pointed out in a comment on my question linked above).

Answer (score 3):

That's because `onload` is already declared and `null` before your script executes.

This is similar to that code :

```
var v=null;
function v(){
    console.log('hi');
}​​​​
console.log(v); // alerts null
```

which is different from this one :

```
function v(){
    console.log('hi');
}​​​​
console.log(v); // alerts the function
```

When you declare a function like this, the declaration and assignment are logically hoisted to the "start" of the scope, so the assignment doesn't really occur *after* the `onload` function is given the `null` value.

That's why it's different from

```
window.onload=...
```

which isn't a declaration but only an assignment which can't be hoisted.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about this. So you're saying there's something like an implicit `var onload = null` that overwrites the hoisted function declaration?

Comment: Yes, the window object is initialized before you run your script. You can type this in the console : `console.log(window, window.onload)`

Answer (score 0):

In the first two cases your are defining a member of window called onload. In the third case your are only defining a function but is not a member of current window.