# Are directly assigned event handlers actual object properties?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I got stuck trying to answer this question: [Explaining odd behavior in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806958/explaining-odd-behavior-in-javascript). While researching, I found that event handlers assigned directly to host objects present a strange behavior: they can be accessed as properties of the object, but somehow they don't appear to be actual properties.

For example, if I define a variable on the global scope, it looks like any other property of `window`:

```
​var foo = "foo";
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'foo'));
// Object {value: "foo", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false}
```

I get the same output if I just assign to `window.foo`, or if I create an implied global (but then [[Configurable]] would be `true`, for known reasons; and, of course, that wouldn't work on strict mode). However, if I try to add an event handler by assigning to `window.onsomething`, I can't read that property with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` (although it's still accessible under `window.onsomething`):

```
window.onresize = function onresize(e) {
    console.log('rsz', e);
}
console.log(window.onresize); // function onresize(){...}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'onresize')); // undefined
```

How do browsers deal with event handlers assigned like that? I suspect the answer to this is also the answer to that other question.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Properties on host objects may behave differently (in different browsers) than pure javascript properties.

Comment: Might see some clues here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: To be honest, none. I was trying to answer the linked question, and couldn't find an explanation that convinced me. This question came up during my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [MDN documentation for `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), it only reports properties that are directly on that object, not in the prototype chain.

For example, it works for:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'location')
```

but not for:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'onresize')
```

probably because `onresize` is on something that window inherits from (therefore in the prototype chain), not on the actual window object itself.

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that, though.
    `window.toString = function() { return "foo"; };`
    `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'toString');`

The above will in fact return a descriptor for 'toString', even though the original definition is on an object higher in the prototype chain.

Comment: I read that, but I read no idea `onresize` was on the prototype chain. Thanks.

Comment: So this indeed answers my question, and the other one. For some reason I thought it would be something more obscure, but that makes total sense.

Comment: @dfreeman I see your point, why isn't a new "own" `onresize` property being created that shadows the prototype-inherited property?

Comment: @dfreeman About the `window.toString` case, it's even weirder when tested on different browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/XMUKn/. As for the event handlers: assigning to `window.onresize` apparently does change `Window.prototype.onresize` (see http://jsfiddle.net/asHP7/). Maybe it's because of this: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#the-windowproxy-object

Comment: @bfavaretto Interesting! I think you're right on the money with the W3 link; and it's not surprising to me given the weirdness of the spec that browsers have differing implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The `window` object is an instance of the `Window` constructor, which has `onresize` as part of its prototype.

Try logging `window` and enabling the `show own properties only` option. `onresize` will not be present, since it is inherited from `Window`. This is why `getOwnProperty` doesn't pick up on it, since it only returns descriptors for properties the object owns, rather than the ones originating in the prototype chain.

Comment: Thanks Asad, that answers my question, and the one I was trying to answer. Makes total sense.

Comment: @bfavaretto dfreeman brings up a good point. My answer as well as the other one don't actually answer your question correctly.

Comment: I'm looking into it now. On the other hand, your answers are perfect for the question I was trying to answer. In that case, it really seems to be a case of shadowing. If we find out it's not, I'll take it back - again (sigh).

Comment: @bfavaretto The problem is a case of *non*-shadowing. When you reassign `onresize`, it should create a new property unique to `window` that is an "own" property. I suppose event handler properties are treated differently.

Comment: Asad, see my recent comment on jfriend's answer. The last link may explain the weird non-shadowing behavior, if that's something browsers really implemented. I'm reaccepting that answer as it does answer what I asked in the title, although there is more to the issue &ndash; possibly due to factors that are implementation dependent.